# Could we get attribute names of a DOM object from angular.element? If yes, how? If no, could we get from other skill in angular and how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

As in the title, could we? how can we do that if that is possible?
Here is what I tried:

```
// Suppose domObj is a dom element
var ngObj = angular.element(domObj);
var attrNames = ngObj[0].attributes;
```

To be more specific, assume we have the following dom element:

```
<div type="custom-type" name="dom-obj" class="dom-class" new-custom-attribute>
</div>
```

The expected result should be an array of string:

```
["type", "name", "class", "new-custom-attribute"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should work.

```
var ngObj = angular.element(domObj);
var attrNames = Array.from(ngObj[0].attributes).map(item => item.name)
```

Comment: Would there be a way to do this in IE also?

Comment: No, as IE doesn't support ES6 features.